# Android: how to animate a circular ProgressBar with a mask?

Tags: android, android-animation, mask, android-progressbar

I want to create a circular `ProgressBar` animating within a custom shape, like this:

[image]

I already know how to create a basic circular `ProgressBar`:

```
<ProgressBar style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="6000"
    android:progress="0"            
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/shape_ring_blue_progress" />
```

**shape_ring_blue_progress.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="270"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="270">
            <shape
                android:shape="ring"
                android:innerRadiusRatio="2.17391304"
                android:thicknessRatio="25.0"
                android:useLevel="true">
                <rotate
                    android:fromDegrees="0"
                    android:pivotX="50%"
                    android:pivotY="50%"
                    android:toDegrees="360" />
                <solid
                    android:color="@color/style_color_blue" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

But I have no clue of how to use a more complex shape and a mask like I want to.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can create custom controls. But in your case, you **may** be able to create your progress bar with object animators: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html